# What questions are on-topic for Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, question-standards

From the [tour](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those involved in the field of teaching mathematics.

and

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about teaching mathematics.

Also,

> Ask about...
>
> - Specific issues with teaching mathematics
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
>
> Don't ask about...
>
> - Anything not directly related to teaching mathematics
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

I am creating this post to gather in one place all the topics that are *not clearly* on-topic.  (This is *not* the same as topics that are *clearly not* on-topic.)  Please post as answers such topics, then users can upvote or downvote these answers, with upvotes meaning they think the topic is on-topic and downvotes meaning they think the topic is not on-topic.

---

#### On-Topic

- [Philosophy of mathematics education](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/667/8571)
- [Math contests](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/666/8571)

#### Off-Topic

- [Sale or donation of used math textbooks](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/665/8571)

Comment: I've edited your post to give quick-links to the answers (with the theory being that there may someday be other categories).  I've also added the tag [tag:faq-proposed], which seems to be new to this meta-site, but which appears on, for example, [Math SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq-proposed/info),  As always, feel free to revert.

Answer (score 7):

### Philosophy of mathematics education

Some examples of questions about this topic (taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_mathematics_education)):

- What is mathematics?, and what accounts have philosophers and other theorists given of it?
- How does mathematics relate to society?
- What are the aims of teaching and learning mathematics?
- What fundamental assumptions underlie the learning and teaching mathematics?
- How do philosophies of mathematics link with mathematics teaching and learning?
- What is the status of mathematics education as knowledge field?

---

According to [this previous Meta question](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/238/77), it seems that this is on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

### Math contests

Questions about designing problems for math contests, or working with students to succeed at these contests.

---

There is currently a tag on main called [math-contests](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-contests) with a description similar to the one given here, so it seems that this is on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

### Sale or donation of used math textbooks

Questions that ask for advice on how to sell or donate used math textbooks.

---

According to [this previous Meta question](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/389/77), it seems that this is not on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

### Popularization of mathematics

Questions about how to show the general public that mathematics is exciting, useful, and beautiful.

---

In this [Meta answer](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/638/77), I presented my opinion that this is on-topic.